# C++11 will cause me rewrite some of the following methods?

Tags: c++, c++11

I read some articles about C++11 move semantic

Now I have more questions

1. Do I need to add a copy construct

   like `ClassA(const ClassA&&)`
2. Do I need to add a = overriding

   like `operator=(ClassA&&)`

Any other changes I need to have?

Or move semantic is totally regarding compiler optimization, I don't need to do anything?

Comment: You should add move semantics for anything that has large amounts of data and that you plan on making temporary copies of( like returning by value from some function ). You can define both and copy and move constructor, so you won't be rewriting anything.

Comment: As far as i know, `const ClassA&&` should be illegal or at least not do what you expect. The move semantics generally change the passed object, which is contrary to the point of passing a `const` reference.

Comment: Thanks, and changes the question.

Answer (score 3):

R-value reference (`&&`) don't exist in C++03, and C++11 doe not generate the move ctor if your class has a copy one, and does not generate a transfer assign if your class as already an assign.

So if you just let your code as it is, it will just work as it did with C++03.

Cosider that, for a class that does not define ctor and assign, the compiler will generate some default impementations that are

- `class::class()` - the usual default, that calls the bases and member defaults.
- `class::class(const class&)` - the usual copy, that calls bases and member-by-member copy
- `class::class(class&&)` - the "move ctor", that calls bases and member-by-member move
- `class& class::operator=(const class&)` - the usual assign by copy that call bases and member-by-member copy
- `class& class::operator=(lass&&)` - the assign by transfer, that calls bases and member by member transfer
- `class::~class()` the dtor, that call mebers and base sdtor in reverse order.

Now, if you implement just copy the move default one is deleted together with the transfer assign, causing whatever "move" operation (copy or assign of a temporary or "casted to temporary) to bind to a copy, thus restoring the old C++03 behavior.

If you impememnt just "*move*", *copy* (and assign) is deleted, causing your class to be "moavable only" (just like `std::unique_ptr`, for example)

If you implement them both, then it is up to you to define how a *move* is different from a *copy*.

Comment: In the copy constructor, I am using a = rhl.a ; b = rhl.b; how to implement using move constructor?

Comment: @AdamLee: `: a(rhl.a); b(rhl.b) { }`. Like you should do in your copy ctor, in fact. But if you just do memberwise copy, why do you even _have_ a copy ctor?

Comment: Move constructor is useful only for rvalue, is that right? If I have a L-value, I need to have both move ctor and copy ctor?

Comment: From your example, I don't see any benefit of move ctor, implemented as the same to copy ctor?

Comment: Move ctor makes sense only if it is not implemented the same as a copy. And copy ctor makes sense only if it is not just a memberwise copy. Copying a r-value, if no r-value copy operation exist will just call the l-value copy: `A&&` converts implicitly into `const A&`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

`class(class&& other) = default;
class(const class& other) = default;`

Beware this will work only when all the members of the class are movable/copyable.
And pointers will be pointing to the same location as the original if the default Copy Cons. is used.

As @Emilio said if you define a Copy Ctor yourself its not appropriate to ask the compiler to generate the default Move Ctor since that can lead to problems.